"Mirroring" data across google sheets
Is it possible to "mirror" data (example below) between separate google sheets?  If not, is there another application that would allow me to do something like this (preferably within google workspace)?
EXAMPLE:  I'd like to create a sheet with a column for Names.  For each name entered, I'd like that entire row of data "mirrored" or copied into another sheet (separate file) corresponding with that name.  If "Name A" is in the Names column, I'd like that row to appear in a separate "Name A" sheet.  For rows with "Name B," the same, etc.  Names would be selected from a pull-down list and every one would have a separate designated sheet.
Here is a link to a mock-up with cell comments explaining this question (feel free to respond here, or within the sheet comments):   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3q1ljoHeIqMtc0mG-2AQTWFsgGpqapLf9awyPq6hxE/edit?usp=sharing
I'm not a programmer, just trying to figure things out as best I can.  Thank you!
Update:  I've been using ChatGPT to try and learn how to do this with Google App Scripts.  However, I've gotten stuck.  Here's the GPT chat in case anyone can offer help:  https://chat.openai.com/share/2ace4404-d44d-4520-9530-46313d589ec8

Questions should be self-contained please [edit] to add any clarification in the question including a sample of your source data and an example of your desired result in markdown text

Short answer is yes. Devil's in the details but you will need a Google Apps  Script solution.

Thanks @Blindspots - I've been using Chat GPT to try and find the right Apps Script ... getting stuck.  But appreciate you pointing me in the right direction!  https://chat.openai.com/share/2ace4404-d44d-4520-9530-46313d589ec8

Thanks for sharing the ChatGPT link. It's interesting the assumptions it made and how it approached troubleshooting.

The whole thing seems doable with plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas, but it is hard to say because there is no sample data in the sample spreadsheet. See filter() to get started. For the 101 on spreadsheet formulas, visit GFCGlobal. The ChatGPT code at the link is mostly hogwash.

Yes, it's possible. You might use the IMPORTRANGE function in a formula to retrieve values from one spreadsheet to another. This function will retrieve an array of values from a specific range. It doesn't include cell attributes like borders, background color, and cell content's rich text formatting.
Another option is to use a Google Workspace add-on or a third-party service. You might also use Google Apps Script and the Google Sheets API.
Regarding the use of chat AI like ChatGPT, it might be more effective for people to know about the features and limitations of Google Sheets and the extensibility and integration options. Try first to use these tools to learn about this, being aware that they might hallucinate, so include time to validate what you learn through these tools.
